# Calling a separate Windows Form using its name as a String

Tags: vb.net

I need to be able to create a Button that can link to a different Windows Form when I click the Button. However, this Button is dynamically generated and can sometimes link to different Forms as per required. For example:

My Button can link to either FormA.vb or FormB.vb. I can make the Button create the String "FormA" or "FormB" as necessary, but I don't know how to call FormA.vb or FormB.vb to the screen.

Thus far, I have been changing Windows Forms by using:

```
FormA.MdiParent = MainForm //My main form window
FormA.Show()

Me.Close()
```

But this obviously will not work with:

```
"FormA".MdiParent = MainForm
"FormA".Show()
```

Simply because they are Strings and not classes.

Is there a way to make my Button link correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should store the form instance in a variable.

Comment: Thanks for replying @SLaks, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you have to import `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Reflection`

First get the form name into the `strCreatedFromButton` then find it.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strCreatedFromButton As String = "Form3"

    Dim frm As New Form
    frm = DirectCast(CreateObjectInstance(strCreatedFromButton), Form)
    frm.Show()
End Sub

Public Function CreateObjectInstance(ByVal objectName As String) As Object
    Dim obj As Object
    Try
        If objectName.LastIndexOf(".") = -1 Then
            objectName = [Assembly].GetEntryAssembly.GetName.Name & "." & objectName
        End If

        obj = [Assembly].GetEntryAssembly.CreateInstance(objectName)

    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    End Try
    Return obj

End Function
```

Comment: Reflection is entirely an overkill for this "standard" scenario I guess.

Comment: Somehow agree. May have better option. Will try to figure out

Comment: Ooh. This worked perfectly. Not quite sure what Reflections do, but it seems to have solved my problem thus far.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Form` type variable to store the reference of either FormA or FormB. Then through polymorphism you can call the `Show()` method that will execute the appropriate instance's method. For example:

```
Dim frm as Form
If <SomeCondition> Then
    frm = New Form1()
Else
    frm = New Form2()
End If

frm.Show()
```

This is just the core concept. You can extend it to match your exact needs.

### Edit

Reading the comments, I'd suggest you just code a large switch (`Select Case` in VB.NET) for your existing forms and then add new cases for new forms as they're added. You could implement the [Factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to pass your string (e.g. "FormA") to the Factory method and let the factory method return appropriate child class object (again using a switch). To minimize deployment effort, you could keep this Factory class and all new form classes in a separate assembly that will work using simple xcopy deployment.

If you must code it once for all future forms, Reflection is the only way you can do it. However, I'd recommend against it.

Comment: I could do that, but there are a lot more Forms than just two. I used FormA and FormB as an example when in reality I have a few tens of these forms - with possibly more coming. I need a more dynamic answer than this.

Comment: Even if `"FormA".Show()` had worked somehow, you'd be using some string variable in the place of `"FormA"`, right? How do you think you'd assign value to that variable?

Comment: That's just it. Maybe I was a little unclear; the String variables are the names of the classes. I'm pulling these Strings from a database and the database is still growing so I can't just do an If-Else fork to decide.

Comment: Why would you recommend against it though? Is there some form of drawback I'm missing?

Comment: @Wakka02: [This extensive discussion](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/101187/are-there-problems-with-using-reflection) covers most of the reasons why Reflection is generally considered to be *code smell*. The consensus is that if you can do it without Reflection, opt for that path. In some scenarios, Reflection can have positive/genuine uses (e.g. data binding, proxies), but this one doesn't seem to be one of them.