# How do I save objects in Configuration of Winforms application?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, configuration

I'm trying to implement functionality to allow the user to select his favorite forms. Favorite forms are forms he/she needs quick access to. To avoid browsing for too long through the ToolStripMenu's.

I try to save a reference to a form in the application configuration. But I'm getting the error

> Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' cannot be converted to
>   'String'.

```
Public Sub SetSetting(ByVal pstrKey As String, ByVal frmFavorite As Form)
    Dim keyExists As Boolean = False
    For Each strKey As String In configuration.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys
        If strKey.Equals(pstrKey) Then
            configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Item(pstrKey).Value = frmFavorite
            keyExists = True
        End If
    Next

    If Not keyExists Then
        configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Add(pstrKey, frmFavorite)
    End If
    configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
End Sub
```

Comment: You should save the name of the form instead. Saving the whole form isn't good, especially not if you change it in the future. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478165/calling-a-separate-windows-form-using-its-name-as-a-string) for how you can open a form by its name. **NOTE:** It creates a new instance of the form, meaning it can't be modified by using its default instance.

Comment: The problem with saving its name is that I have to save its parameters, which are again objects. And it's not an issue if it creates a new instance.

Comment: Hmm... Then it seems better to save the entire form. You could serialize it to a base64-string. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2861749/3740093).

Comment: Yes (in answer to deleted comment), using binary serialization you will be able serialize the entire form and all its contents. By serializing it to a memory stream you can then get it as a byte array which can be converted into a Base64-string.

Comment: @ISeeSharp Don't think about serializing entire form. It doesn't make sense. It's enough to bind properties which are important to you to settings. This way wen you load each form, those properties will load from settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only store `string` values in the application config file, no objects.
But just store the name of the Form in the config file. 
When starting your application create the form via reflection like shown in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee794614.aspx) Object Factory example.

```
Public Class ObjectFactory

  Public Shared Function CreateAnObject(ByVal ObjectName As String) As Object
        Dim Assem = [Assembly].GetExecutingAssembly()

        Dim myType As Type = Assem.GetType(ObjectName.Trim)
        Dim o As Object = Nothing
        Try
            o = Activator.CreateInstance(myType)
        Catch oEx As TargetInvocationException
            MessageBox.Show(oEx.ToString)
        End Try

        Return o
    End Function
End Class
```

...

```
Dim formName as String = configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Item(<YourSettingKey>)

Dim oForm As Form = _
        ObjectFactory.CreateAnObject(formName)
```

Comment: What about a form with parameters which are objects?

Comment: You are talking about constructor parameters of the form like `new Form(o1, o2, ...)` ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean

Comment: In this case I would recommend to [Serialize/Deserialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx) the whole Form object.